# « (Compare, mix) apples and oranges » : les fruits ou le textile etc. ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, alimentation

Laquelle des expressions « [mélanger des choux et des carottes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9langer_des_choux_et_des_carottes) » (aussi [comparer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparer_des_choux_et_des_carottes)) et « [mélanger les torchons et les serviettes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9langer_les_torchons_et_les_serviettes) » se rapproche le plus de *(compare, [mix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mix_apples_and_oranges#English)) [apples and oranges](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apples_and_oranges)* pour la *comparaison de choses qui ne sont pas comparables* ou le *mélange de deux choses qui sont complètement différentes* et le choix du verbe est-il déterminant pour le choix de l'expression en français ? Si ce sont les deux on en établira les nuances de sens et on en comparera les fréquences d'emploi. Y a-t-il d'autres expressions qui sont de même sens ?

Comment: Il y a une forte dimension sociologique dans l'histoire des torchons et des serviettes. Elle n'a pas l'air d'exister dans ‘to mix apple and oranges’ mais qui sait, à une époque où l'orange était un fruit rare…

Comment: Lorsque j'ai appris mes premières bases d'algèbre, ma prof en revenait systématiquement aux pommes et aux oranges pour nous rappeler que les x ne s'additionnent pas aux y. D'autres gens, d'autres régions du Québec, m'ont indiqué par la suite qu'ils avaient été exposés au même exemple.

Comment: @Montéedelait Ouais, Wikipédia en parle dans son article en anglais sur [_apples and oranges_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges), il parle aussi des pommes et des poires comme la réponse pour l'Europe. Je suis étonné de voir que des trucs si usuels soient si peu documentés. Je dirais que moi aussi j'ai entendu ça, je ne saurais dire si c'est sous l'influence de l'anglais ou non, on peut faire une réponse pour le Québec sans problème, de toutes façons on est sorti du cadre des deux expressions que je présentais et qui sont peut-être moins usuelles qu'on pourrait le croire...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'expression la plus proche de "compare apples and oranges" est "[comparer des pommes et des poires](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/comparer+des+pommes+et+des+poires.html)". Je n'avais jamais entendu "mélanger des choux et des carottes", et l'expression "mélanger les torchons et les serviettes" porte un jugement de valeur (on mélange du "propre" et du "sale") alors que "pommes et poires" sont au même niveau.

Comment: Était-ce à l'origine un [belgicisme](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7Jj625vvHckC&pg=PA462&dq=additionner+pommes+et+poires+lebouc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz-9ututrhAhVSrVkKHSL1DPQQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=additionner%20pommes%20et%20poires%20lebouc&f=false) ? Est-ce présent partout en Europe francophone ? C'est le genre d'expression qu'on devrait trouver avec celles présentées au Wiktionnaire, je suis perplexe.

Comment: il est possible que ce soit un belgicisme. Il faudrait d'autres sources que moi pour vérifier.Ceci étant dit, le Wiktionnaire est un site participatif sans aucune garantie d'exhaustivité, et le lien que je donne vers linguee n'est pas uniquement constitué de sites belges (loin de là)

Comment: D'accord sur tous les points.