# Quelle est la signification de l'expression "on additionne pas des choux et des carottes"?

Tags: traduction, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai vu cette expression dans des forums de discussion, qui ne parlaient pas de recettes de cuisine...

Comment: Additionally this is just an example among an infinity of other combinations. *choux* et *carrottes* can be substitued by any vegetable, fruit or even objects (although I usually hear it with fruits & vegetables indeed...)

Comment: @chqrlie > 1) Maybe you can ask on https://tezos.stackexchange.com/ , there's not much activity there neither. 2) Do you have any sources about this being the idiomatic expression? I've heard it a lot with *pommes* & *poires* myself, very seldom with these vegetables. I also find [the appropriate translation with the fruits  as a search term](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/additionner+des+pommes+et+des+poires.html) while none is coming up [with your vegetables](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=additionner+des+choux+et+des+carottes)

Comment: @LaurentS.: well I have some 58 years of French practice as a native speaker, but I have a scientific bias, and this expression seems to be used more in the field of mathematics: https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/76404

Comment: I'm not that old myself, but still reasonably old though (I'm 40). I'm also all ok to hear that being belgian may introduce a bias, but it seems that [even on French sources](https://images.math.cnrs.fr/spip.php?page=forum&id_article=417) *pommes* & *poires* is widely used...

Comment: @LaurentS.: the choice of vegetables vs fruits may be geographically related, or specific to a field of science or even to a particular period in time... *choux et carottes* are more obviously different than *pommes et poires*, especially to recluse math buffs.

Comment: I agree, indeed these vegetables are more different than these fruits. I researched a bit further and indeed was able to find [sources with *choux et carottes*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparer_des_choux_et_des_carottes) while I didn't find such sources with *pommes et poires*, which seems to be widely used though as I google these terms. Note that the translation on wiktionary cites "translations" to German (same fruits) and English (Apple and oranges), this may explain that.

Comment: Maintenant que la question a été changée, elle correspond à ce site et j'aimerais retirer mon "close vote", mais cela n'est pas possible...

Comment: Voir aussi [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34831).

Answer (score 2):

Cette expression semble plutôt utilisée en mathématiques : https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/76404

Il existe une variante aussi courante *on n'ajoute pas des pommes et des poires* ou encore *comparer des pommes et des poires* pour désigner l'erreur consistant à mélanger dans un calcul des nombres représentant des grandeurs exprimées dans des unités différentes. Le résultat n'a pas de sens, et ce type d'erreur conduit parfois à des catastrophes comme l'échec du [Mars Climate Orbiter](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1999-oct-01-mn-17288-story.html).

En anglais on peut utiliser une expression équivalente avec *fruits and vegetables* ou *apples and oranges*.

Comment: Elle est très utilisée en dehors des mathématiques...  si tu fais une recherche google tu trouveras  de nombreux domaines (presse et forums). Pommes et poires montre moins de résultats.